# Asking for comparison of design of two code snippets giving same functionality

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, scope, iterative-review

I had asked for the [review of the part of a jQuery](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52742/how-can-this-jquery-be-changed-to-be-more-manageable-and-readable) and as per the answer I made changes in the file. Now after making the changes (mainly moving from triggers to functions) I am not so sure whether I got enough benefit in the structure of the code. I think I can reason about the code better but I wanted some comments on the changes done.

Can I ask for a review of [two code files](https://gist.github.com/anshbansal/9fe120621ca96995afd2) (both written by me) in one question for comparison of the structure and design of the two? No change in the functionality is there.

Comment: [Comparative reviews are fine](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1773/9357), as are [iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that the code is already on-topic, and you're still seeking actual reviews (not "which of these is better?" or anything like that), multiple code blocks *can* be reviewed in a comparative manner.

Such questions should be tagged as [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review).

Comment: Probably another discussion but.... Do we really need that tag?

Comment: I can't quite answer that myself.  I think it might be useful, but I'm also a bit hesitant about some meta tags.

Comment: Noted and [question posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/53896/for-these-javascript-files-what-are-the-good-bad-and-ugly-aspects-of-the-struct)